# Spacing a textview

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm trying to make a basic text-based adventure game in Android studio. I'm using a `textview` to display the map. It has weird spacing, like this:

Current Layout:

[image: Current Layout]

However, I want it to be spaced out like this:

Desired Layout:

[image: Desired Layout]

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a monospaced font.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app supports API 16 and higher, you can use the `android:fontFamily` attribute on your `TextView`:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="monospace"/>
```

[image]